# Braintree Drop-in Payment UI Customization

Tags: java, swift, braintree

I'm trying to use #braintree Drop-in Payment UI in iOS. If someone disables some buttons e.g for Apple Pay, Vemmo or credit card, the space for these buttons still exists as an empty space in the action sheet. Is there any way to eliminate this space?

[image]

[image]

Additionally, when you make a choice sometimes there is a delay in the response. So the user isn't sure if the button is pressed. Is there a way to avoid pressing the button twice or dismiss the action sheet once a button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Our action sheet is set to a fixed height regardless of payment methods. You can [fork our iOS Drop-in repository](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in) to change the height, however, I would recommend referencing [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/) to ensure adapting this would meet their standards.

Testing my own iOS integration, there is not a delay on the button press. Please reach out to our [support team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) for more specifics around the delays you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @jacqueD for your answer. I also have a problem with the Drop-in UI that once it is appeared, the buttons of the background controller are still active. Do you have ideas on this?

Comment: You should be able to create a `disableButtons` function and set `button.enabled = false` for the buttons you would like to disable.